# Calling on variables from other files in python3? Can someone help me with this little issue I am having?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I am fairly new to python, and I am trying to call on other variables between files.  Here is what I am trying to do as simple as possible:

**file1.py** -

```
from file2 import *

global food
food = "pizza"

eat()
```

**file2.py** -

```
def eat():
        print ("I want to eat some", food)
```

In my little brain, this should just print out "I want to eat some pizza", but instead I am getting python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 6, in <module>
    eat()
  File "<path>/file2.py", line 2, in eat
    print ("I want to eat some", food)
NameError: name 'food' is not defined
```

Any help as to why this might be happening, or a solution would be highly appreciated.

Additional info: My main goal is to consolidate code in a program to make the initial source code easier to read and shorter.  I understand that this may not be a best practice, but right now I am just experimenting and learning as I go.  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: (As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.)

Comment: food isnt in its scope, try passing it to the `eat` function as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try to stay away from globals, instead, use parameters to directly pass values into the scope of a function.

main.py

```
from file2 import *
food = "pasta"

eat(food)
```

file2.py

```
def eat(food: str):
    print ("I want to eat some " + food)
```